# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.(opencv ?)

Tags: android-studio

An error occurred suddenly.
The error message is as follows.

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

[image]

What's wrong?

Additionally, every 'R.' in the code has a red underline.

**Solution**

**I used .png as the background image, but changed it to .jpg and it was fixed.**

Comment: Please post your solution as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just accidentally changed the images "png -> jpg" 
                                (The background image I used)

However, some images were left as png.
I am not sure whether it is a project problem or an image file problem.

If you have a problem like me, 
If you can not solve it by using other methods,
It can be one way.